# In Rust's pyO3, how do I represent a custom Python class that's implemented in Python, such that the pyo3 struct can check types?

Tags: python, rust, msgpack, pyo3

I'm writing a custom MessagePack serializer to add to an old Python project that uses MessagePack extensively. In particular, I often have lists of objects built up that I need to serialize all at once, but the GIL prevents this, so I want to use Rust to do it, and be fast in other ways besides.

I have already gotten fundamental Python types to serialize this way, but I want to serialize some of the custom classes that my Python app has, as well, and would prefer not to port those into Rust—even though pyO3 would make that easy to do, I'm nervous about adding a hard dependency on this Rust code, and would like a fallback to the standard Python MessagePack library.

So I started by writing a struct to represent a singleton:

```rust
struct PyFinalRule(PyAny);
unsafe impl PyTypeInfo for PyFinalRule {
    const NAME: &'static str = "FinalRule";
    const MODULE: Option<&'static str> = Option::Some("LiSE.util");
    type AsRefTarget = PyAny;

    fn type_object_raw(py: Python<'_>) -> *mut PyTypeObject {
        let modu = py.import("LiSE.util").unwrap();
        let final_rule = modu.getattr("FinalRule").unwrap();
        final_rule.get_type_ptr()
    }
}
unsafe impl PyNativeType for PyFinalRule {}
```

I was expecting to be able to use `PyFinalRule::is_type_of` to check when a `PyAny` object is really an instance of `FinalRule`. Instead, `PyFinalRule::is_type_of` always returns `false` when passed the one instance of the `FinalRule` singleton. It returns `true` when passed the `FinalRule` type object, but that's not very useful, since the app serializes the instance and not the type object.

How do I get `PyFinalRule::is_type_of` to really check the type?

Comment: Accessing Python objects requires holding the GIL even from Rust, so I don't see how porting to Rust will help you avoid the GIL.

Comment: I still have to *extract* the data while inside the GIL, but can *serialize* it outside. Copying is cheaper than serializing.

Comment: Ah, ok. If serializing is that expensive then you're right.

Comment: In fact there's already a very fast msgpack serializer for python, `ormsgpack`, but my app does so much serializing so often that I really want to optimize it every way I can.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any unsafe code or complex things to check that, it's simple:

```rust
fn is_instance_of_final_rule(py: Python<'_>, object: &PyAny) -> PyResult<bool> {
    let module = py.import("LiSE.util")?;
    let final_rule = module.getattr("FinalRule")?;
    object.is_instance(final_rule)
}
```

Of course, I'd recommend to cache the `FinalRule` object somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with for `type_object_raw`:

```rust
    fn type_object_raw(py: Python<'_>) -> *mut PyTypeObject {
        let modu = py.import("LiSE.util").unwrap();
        let final_rule = modu.getattr("FinalRule").unwrap();
        let typ = final_rule.extract::<&PyType>().unwrap();
        typ.get_type_ptr()
    }
```

Adapted a bit from [Adesoji Alu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77731825/1211606).